# Moving to Spain from Germany with an EU blue card

Tags: germany, spain, blue-card

I am an EU blue card holder living in Germany for about 4 years. Recently I got a job offer in Spain as Java Developer, which I intend to take. But the company and I are oblivious to the visa process. I went ahead and did the interview, hoping that my EU blue card would allow me to acquire the necessary permit to work in Spain easily.

But I fail to find any decent information on this. I found [a leaflet (pdf)](http://extranjeros.empleo.gob.es/es/InformacionInteres/FolletosInformativos/archivos/triptico_tarjeta_azul_eng.pdf) dated 2011 with information. But I'm afraid most of it could be outdated. Does anyone have any sort of knowledge or experience with moving to different countries with an EU blue card?

Any kind of information would be very helpful.

Comment: I am currently in the same situation, Can you please share how you managed to change the german permanent residency to a Spanish one? didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: I did not change German PR to Spanish PR, rather I obtained EU PR in Germany and then after a year, once I managed to get a job in Spain, I requested for a Spanish PR. But of course, this means I gave up EU PR issued by Germany. Most of the paper work was done by the lawyers hired by my company, so unfortunately I cannot give you all the details. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been three years, and I have finally managed to get my residence permit in Spain. However EU blue card was of no use. EU blue card in Spain is very much unknown.

I had to get EU permanent residency in Germany and, after a while, I applied for permanent residency in Spain and have managed to get it. Similar to the EU blue card, EU permanent residency does not allow one to work in any other country than the one which issued it. It just allows you stay for a longer period in another EU country before returning to the origin country.

Comment: Thanks for updating us.

Comment: (+1) The permanent residency is also supposed to offer some protection in case you become unable to work as your right to stay is not tied to your employment anymore. I don't know anybody who made use of that so I don't know how it works in practice.

Comment: just a note, there is two types: permanent residence, and EU permanent residence. If its filed under EU law, then it is possible to move to another EU country and apply to work/live there.

Comment: @Asher I did have EU permanent residence, but still it does not allow you work in other EU countries. It makes the process little easier, to get Permanent residence in other country, but it does not entitle you to live/work in another country,

Comment: "It just allows you stay for a longer period in another EU country before returning to the origin country" this is patently false. A right of permanent residence never expires, the card itself acts only as proof of the right and needs to be renewed every 5 years.

Comment: @Ozzy I wrote what exactly I was told by my case office at Auslanderamt. I am not saying the right or PR expires. It is just legally you are not allowed to stay in other EU country for longer than 6 months without returning to the country that issued the PR. I am fairly certain I also confirmed this with other resources back then.